# Can't subclass DispatchGroup - "only visible via the Objective-C runtime"?

Tags: swift, swift3, objective-c-runtime

It's not possible to subclass `DispatchGroup`, how to do so?

Note:

## this has finally been fixed in iOS 10+

Example, carry a stateful package with a group,

```
class PushDispatchGroup: DispatchGroup {
    var sentIds: [(tableName: String, rowId: String)] = []
}
```

thanks to shallowThought for pointing out this is fixed in iOS10.

Comment: Why are you trying to subclass `DispatchGroup`? Perhaps your question should be about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your code compiles fine here. I can not create an instance due to `error: 'DispatchGroupPlus' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers`  though.

Comment: @JoeBlow That doesn't mean you should be subclassing it. Compose, don't inherit.

Comment: hi @shallowThought - that's weird; what version of Xcode / Swift are you using exactly ??  8.2 (8C38) here.  I'll screenshot it.

Comment: @JoeBlow it's not at all bad form. If a guy came asking "How can I put a screw in with a hammer?", answering " Use a screw driver instead" is a perfectly valid answer. Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: @JoeBlow inheritance comes with a **lot** of draw backs. There's a reason there's a ubiquitous push against it in recent days, across all languages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130890/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-joe-blow).

Comment: hi @AlexanderMomchliov !  RobNapier has given the **actual answer**, it's a wrapper for a C struct, not a obj-c class.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I merely suggested taking a different approach, which is likely better supported by the amenities Swift has to offer. It's a perfectly reasonable response, and your whaling about "modern software engineering since the 1970", "oo" is just foolish.

Comment: @JoeBlow Yep, and I'm happy this question was answered.

Comment: @JoeBlow Also part of Rob's answer: "As various commenters have said, you also shouldn't be doing this". I wonder who that could be.

Comment: @JoeBlow For the record: I am using Xcode 8.2 (8C38) and your code build fine here. 
 I just read the following comment in `OS_object`: _* To provide backward deployment of ObjC objects in Swift on pre-10.12
* SDKs, OS_object classes can be marked as OS_OBJECT_OBJC_RUNTIME_VISIBLE.
* When compiling with a deployment target earlier than OS X 10.12 (iOS 10.0,
* tvOS 10.0, watchOS 3.0) the Swift compiler will only refer to this type at
* runtime (using the ObjC runtime)._ If I set the deployment target to iOS9.x, I get the error as well.

Comment: ahh!  @shallowThought, you are building to iOS10 !  facepalm, that's it !  I was building to 9.  Brilliant thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work for me on Xcode 10.2, I don't think it's fixed in iOS 10+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how to inherit from a class which is 'only visible via the Objective-C runtime'?

You don't.

This is not wrapped around a proper "object" the way you're thinking about it. It's wrapped around a `dispatch_group`, which is a C struct. This class is not designed to be subclassed and does not bridge in a normal way to ObjC, so you can't subclass it there either.

"Objects" that bridge directly to low level C types often have very unusual structures that parts of the system are hard-coded to know how to deal with (this happens all the time with toll-free bridging like `NSString` and `CFString`). In many cases, the types are designed to be identical in memory layout through careful choice of structure (I haven't picked apart `DispatchGroup`, but it looks like one from this group). When that's true, you can't add any storage because then the memory layout will be different and you break the bridging.

As various commenters have said, you also *shouldn't* be doing this, which is why there is no easy answer for *how* to do this. Classes that are not explicitly designed for subclassing are intentionally difficult or impossible to subclass in Swift (this comes up regularly around less tricky types than `DispatchGroup`, and the answer is the same: it's intentional; don't do it).

Comment: "It's wrapped around a dispatch_group, which is a C struct" ah, fantastic, thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering @RobNapier, how does one know that (in this case, say) `DispatchGroup` is actually a C struct wrapper?  (When I click to "Definition", I'm not intelligent enough to understand from that, what it is.)

Comment: First, by knowing that `dispatch_group` exists, that it's a struct, and that it is bridged into ARC (and I've previously studied how that works). `DispatchGroup` is an `OS_object`, which means it's one of the `libSystem` "fake" objects. See `os/object.h` for some commentary on it. You'll also see why this might compile some places but not others (they made changes in 10.12 for instance). But even if it compiled, it would be very dangerous (which is why I'm sure they added the error).

Comment: If this kind of stuff interests you, then you definitely want to read everything fish has written. Specifically start here: http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html

Comment: Jumping to the definition of `DispatchGroup` I see `open class DispatchGroup {}`, which I read as "You are welcome to subclass me. I am explicitly designed to do so. I am `open`". What is wrong with my consideration?

Comment: "Open" was just added in Swift 3. They haven't audited every Cocoa class to decide which should be open so "open" is the default for the Cocoa importer. If it were designed for subclassing, there would almost always be "subclassing notes" in the docs to explain how. It is very rare that a class can be arbitrarily subclassed (which is a major problem with subclassing, and a reason to avoid it: subclassing almost always requires special knowledge that isn't in the interface).

Comment: @RobNapier I see. Thanks!