# Why is DispatchGroup deinit never called?

Tags: swift

```
final class MyDispatchGroup: DispatchGroup {
    deinit {
        print("DEINIT")
    }
}

var dispatchGroup: MyDispatchGroup? = MyDispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup = nil
```

I couldn't find any information about it and I'm curious why does it behave this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dispatch objects don’t conform to all sorts of inheritance behavior. Try overriding `init`. (And if you look at the header for the designated initializer says “`/* not inherited */`”.) Or try implementing another method in your subclass and then calling it from your instance. Or keep a strong reference for your class and look for it in the “Debug Memory Graph” navigator and you won’t find it there. None of this traditional inheritance behavior works.

Dispatch objects have a complicated history. Originally they were exposed via a C API and didn’t conform to ARC. Then they added ARC capabilities (which could be turned on or off with a compile-time flag) to this C API object. And then they wrapped the C API with a more traditional Swift object class definition, but are really still using this old C API behind the scenes.

Bottom line, `DispatchGroup` doesn’t support subclassing. [Can't subclass DispatchGroup - "only visible via the Objective-C runtime"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41210629/1271826) suggests that this has been “fixed” in iOS 10+, but it is not. My only question is why, given all of that, and after all this time, they haven’t yet declared `DispatchGroup` to be `final`.

Comment: I find these dark corners of Swift most interesting. Everything you say is true and can be easily verified, but nothing in the Dispatch framework’s [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/f13ea5dcc055e5d2d7c02e90d8c9907ca9dc72e1/src/swift/Wrapper.swift) suggestes this would be the case.

Comment: If you dig further, you find [this file](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/f13ea5dcc055e5d2d7c02e90d8c9907ca9dc72e1/src/swift/Dispatch.apinotes) which seems to do the mappings from C primitives to Swift types and is probably the answer to OP’s "why?".

Comment: I'm sure it's a dupe, but I posted bug report, suggesting that they update the documentation and, if possible, declare `DispatchGroup` as `final`.